Adding hetzner default gateway manually before I am able to ping google.com
I used opnsense as natgateway for my private network. everything is working fine except that I have to manually declare my default gateway everything the system before I can ping from a vm in the private network.
/etc/network/interfaces
auto ens10
iface ens10 inet dhcp
   post-up ip ro add default via 10.1.0.1
   dns-nameservers 1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8

but I have to maually type this
ip ro add default via 10.1.0.1

on the command line to be able to ping google.com
Is there a way I can make it permanent so that I don't have retype this all the time
